# The problem related to unit test CSharp , Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am a beginner in testing. I have some problems. I develop the APIs according on three layer:
this is repo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwvA2.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vk8U.png) this is a function in  a service : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BnLm.png) An I write test [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkYfU.png) It causes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQc54.png) please help me. thank you for reading

The ways to resolve this problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)